# $x^2 * (x+1)^2 = (x^2+x)^2$|| I do not understand this

Tags: exponentiation

$$x^4(x+1)^4(2x+1)$$ I was solving this question (I had integrate it)
but I did not know how to solve it! So I saw the solution and it says

$$x^4(x+1)^4 = (x^2+x)^4$$

and I do not get how that works? Can someone prove it, please?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good
question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x^4(x+1)^4 = \left(x(x+1)\right)^4=(x^2+x)^4$$

Comment: +1 for your fast answer. But I have not understood the title of the question.What are $||$?

Answer (score 0):

$$\int x^4(x+1)^4(2x+1){\rm d}x=\int (x^2+x)^4{\rm d}(x^2+x)=\frac{1}{5}(x^2+x)^5+C.$$